# NOT EXISTS - SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in my sql database

[image]

I need to write SQL query, that will find customers that didn't rent any movie. Looking at the table, those customers have id of 3 and 4

I've tried this, but it's not working. I seem to be missing simple logic in creating queries

```
SELECT name, last_Name, movie_name
FROM Customers, Rented_movies
WHERE Rented_movies.customer_id = Customers.customer_id
AND NOT EXISTS(customer_id);
```

Any help? Much appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE customer_id NOT IN (SELECT customer_id FROM Rented_movies);
```

If you MUST use a NOT EXIST statement, then this should also work:

```
SELECT * FROM Customers C
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Rented_movies WHERE customer_id = C.customer_id);
```

Comment: yes that is it. thank you very much! i get the logic now...this is nesting queries right?

Comment: @fokz8 yes this is an example of a nested query.

Comment: thanks... and not "not exists" is not a must. was first thing i came up with :)

Answer (score 2):

try this way fellow

`SELECT name, last_Name, movie_name
FROM   Customers 
WHERE  customer_id NOT IN (SELECT customer_id FROM Rented_movies)`

Comment: This is not valid based on the schema provided. Change "WHERE ID" to "WHERE customer_id" and it becomes valid.

Comment: welcome :)     if this work for you don't forgot to mark like a good answer this help another people too in the future